# Custom date and time for appointment form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, calendar, appointment

Hello people of stackoverflow.

I want to know if maybe anyone of you knows, if there is a plugin that can set available/unavailable dates including hour schedule in calendar, so the customer can choose her appointment.

I already got the form, but the list for available dates is written in  so you have to manually edit them in code and it would be so much better if editing is possible directly on wordpress. So instead of choosing the dates from option values i would like to have a popup calendar and available hours for that day.

Any help or guidance to help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a software you can implement into your wordpress that works as you have described, it's called "Salonized", maybe it will help.